# QGIS and metainformation ISO 19115

Tags: qgis, metadata, iso-19115

I'm using QGIS, but not for a long time. I'm editing and saving shapes and geotiffs. And I'm happy how this works. I'm wondering if there's a way to import and export metadata ISO 19115, while saving and loading files. In a way that it is stored, together with the shapes or tiffs? I hate to loose the connection between data and metadata. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension that works with ISO 19115. It is called Metatools. You can import/export an .xml file, view, edit and validate it. It also recognizes the metadata-file when opening a shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

The [GeoCat Bridge QGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geocatbridge/) is the answer to your question:

> GeoCat Bridge offers a one-click publishing experience for QGIS
> Desktop. Create great looking maps and publish them to GeoServer,
> MapServer and share via GeoNetwork opensource metadata catalog. Your
> data is uploaded as a GeoPackage or shared PostGIS database. GeoCat
> Bridge brings our celebrated symbology output to the QGIS Desktop to
> share your cartography online.